# Rename and Insert erro TreeStore ExtJS 4.1.1

Tags: extjs4, rename, extjs4.1, treepanel

Good Evening guys,

When I update the method it does not save all model items like "tipoNo" and "pai". Someone know what i can do ?

**Request Payload**

This is the information sent in the request.

```
{"parentId":1,"nome":"qwfqwfqw"}
```

**Model:**

Fields in the my model.

```
fields : [ {
    name : 'id',
    type : 'long'
},{
    name : 'pai',
    type : 'long'
}, {
    name : 'nome',
    type : 'string'
}, {
    name : 'tipoNo',
    type : 'string'
}, {
    name : 'leaf',
    type : 'boolean',
    convert : function(value, record) {
        var no = record.get('tipoNo');
        return (no == "CLIENTE" ? true : false);
    }
} ],
```

**Proxy**

Proxy to requisite information on the server.

```
proxy : {
    type : 'rest',
    url : Webapp.link('node'),
    reader : {
        type : 'json',
        root : 'nodes',
        idProperty : 'id'
    },
    writer : {
        type : 'json',
        writeAllFields : false
    }
}
```

**Controller Method**

```
/**
 * Rename
 * 
 * @param {Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing} editor
 * @param {Object} e                            
 */
updateList : function (editor, e) {
    var node = e.record;
    node.save({
        success: function(list, operation) {
            console.log("updated");
        },
        failure: function(list, operation) {
            var error = operation.getError(),
                msg = Ext.isObject(error) ? error.status + ' ' + error.statusText : error;

            Ext.MessageBox.show({
                title: 'Notificação',
                msg: msg,
                icon: Ext.Msg.ERROR,
                buttons: Ext.Msg.OK
            });
        }
    });
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution in this case:

```
/**
 * Executa a edição
 * 
 * @param {Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing} editor
 * @param {Object} e                            
 */
updateList : function (editor, e) {
    var node = e.record;
    var me = this;
    var nodeTree = me.getNodeTree();

    var method = (node.data.id !== undefined ? 'PUT' : 'POST');
    var post = {
            id: (node.data.id !== undefined ? null : node.data.id),
            nome: node.data.nome,
            pai: (node.data.parentId == -1 ? null : node.data.pai),
            tipoNo: node.data.tipoNo
    };
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: Webapp.link("node"),
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }, 
        jsonData: post,
        method: method,
        success: function(response){
            var text = response.responseText;
            console.log(text);
            nodeTree.refreshView();
        }
    });

},
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your proxy configuration. Your JSON writer has the `writeAllFields` property set to false. From the [Ext.data.writer.Json](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.writer.Json-cfg-writeAllFields) documentation:

```
True to write all fields from the record to the server.
If set to false it will only send the fields that were modified.
```

So any fields that have not been touched will not be sent back to the server. If you want all properties to be sent to the server, set `writeAllFields` to true (or just remove it, since true is the default) and try again.

Comment: I tried doing this, but when I send the information I have serialization problem.